# IOS Application Loading Data From Web

Tags: ios, web, uiimageview, load

I am trying to load data from web with few simple steps:

```
NSData *JSONData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"******"]];

NSObject *json = [JSONData objectFromJSONData];
NSArray *arrayOfStreams = [json valueForKeyPath:@"programs"];
NSDictionary *stream = [arrayOfStreams objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[stream valueForKey:@"image"]];
NSURL *urlForImage1 = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSData *imageData1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlForImage1];
_screenForVideo1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData1];
```

But the problem is I am doing 30 of this right after my application launches...
I want to load about 5 of them, and than load others. Because when I try to load all of them at the same time, my app is not launching all of them loaded... 
Is there any way that I can load first few of them, and wait, and than load others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for loading them, you should probably display a spinner, start loading the image in background and then replace the spinner with the image once it’s ready.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    UIActivityIndicator *spinner = …;
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startLoadingImage)
         withObject:nil];
  }
- (void) startLoadingImage {
    // You need an autorelease pool since you are running
    // in a different thread now.
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo"];
    // All GUI updates have to be done from the main thread.
    // We wait for the call to finish so that the pool won’t
    // claim the image before imageDidFinishLoading: finishes.
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageDidFinishLoading:)
        withObject:image waitUntilDone:YES];
    [pool drain];
}

- (void) imageDidFinishLoading: (UIImage*) image {
    // fade spinner out
    // create UIImageView and fade in
}
```

Comment: oh it just confused me... let me think.